# How do I obtain the duplicated values of two ArrayLists?

Tags: java, arraylist, duplicates, array-merge

Let's say I have 2 ArrayList of Points:

1. `(0,2)->(0,3)->(0,4)`
2. `(0,2)->(0,3)->(0,6)`

And I want to obtain a new list : `(0,2)->(0,3)`

How do I do that?

**current solution**

Using two foreach loops to compare the two lists, element by element. I think it's a very inefficient way. Are there any other ways?

Comment: Should they have the same order? Can there be points in the middle that are just skipped?

Comment: @Bubletan not necessarily in the same order. Skipping points in the middle? What do u mean by that?

Comment: Okay, the second one was just another question in case the order would've mattered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`List#retainAll(Collection<?> c)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#retainAll(java.util.Collection)) method, which:

> Retains only the elements in this list that are contained in the specified collection (optional operation). In other words, removes from this list all of its elements that are not contained in the specified collection.

```
List<Point> first = ...
List<Point> second = ...
first.retainAll(second);
```

Comment: You might want to mention that there are a lot of methods in the JCF which correspond to concepts in Set theory. Anyway +1.

Comment: This is not much more efficient than OPs solution: it still O(n^2). Using the `Set` for `second` will make it faster for big collections.

Comment: One disadvantage being it modifies the original list(since OP says new list)

Answer (score 0):

If large lists, add elements of one list to a `HashSet` and iterate other while keep adding elements to the new list which the `HashSet` `contains`

```
List<Point> list1 = new ArrayList<Point>(Arrays.asList(new Point[]{new Point(0,2), new Point(0,3), new Point(0,4)}));
List<Point> list2 = new ArrayList<Point>(Arrays.asList(new Point[]{new Point(0,2), new Point(0,3), new Point(0,6)}));
Set<Point> setList1 = new HashSet<Point>(list1);
List<Point> intersection  = list2.stream().filter( l -> setList1.contains(l)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Time complexity,
Adding to Set = O(n), Iterating list = O(k) time hashset lookup O(1)
~ overall O(n)